# How can I make a div inside my textarea drag/movable to change its position inside the text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have a textarea with movable chip elements. However, I can't find anything that would allow me to move such an element e.g.

```
This (is) Sparta
```

to

```
This Sparta (is)
```

using drag&drop ([see jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f7wztkyw/)). How can I accomplish this?

Comment: It seems to work if you add an `id` attribute to your draggable element?

Comment: @Supersharp Yes, it started indeed to work as I added an `id` element to the draggable. :) The only thing that is not working is the caret indicator. It does not show me where the element is going to be dropped like when you move text in the [ace editor](https://ace.c9.io/build/kitchen-sink.html).